# Python - Tkinter, how do I correctly use the PhotoImage in this situation?

Tags: python, tkinter, gimp

How do I correctly use the label to display an image in tkinter since every time the window is opened, the image is displayed, but it appears completely white, not showing its relevant content?

I have this doubt because the format of the image used in the following code is PNG, and the image is transparent with solid content, yet after running the code, it appears only as a totally white label. For more useful information, I refer to this code as an initial stage of the hangman game, the image in question is stored in the variable image2, which is where the error is occurs. The variable image1 is not called in this case.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.configure(background="#4F4F4F")
root.option_add('*tearOff', False)


def images():
    image1 = PhotoImage(file='Boneco1.png')
    image1 = image1.subsample(1, 3)
    image2 = PhotoImage(file="Bonecolindo.png")
    image2 = image2.subsample(1, 1)
    return [image1, image2]


class Game:

    def __init__(self):
        root.title("TWG")
        root.geometry("900x700")
        label = ttk.Label(root, text="The Words Game", font=("Times New Roman", 18), background="#4F4F4F", foreground="white")
        label.place(relx=0.5, y=30, anchor="center")
        image = Label(root, image=images()[0], borderwidth=2, relief="solid", bg="gray")
        image.place(x=0, rely=0.5, anchor="center")
        imagel = Label(root, image=images()[1])
        imagel.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor="center")


Game()
root.mainloop()
```

[This is the image I'm referring to, it's transparent in PNG format, has the correct alpha channel, I used GIMP, an image editing application, to make the transparency, the problem is described above, which refers to when the code is run, the image appears completely white...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNcP9.png)

[The image is displayed blank in the window. Above, there is a detailed explanation of what I have already done to try to solve the problem, because the code runs, but not as intended!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfZO2.png)

1- I have reformulated the image into various compatible formats, and now I'm using the PNG format.

2- I went an image editor, GIMP, and created an alpha channel for the image background. I tried reformulating the code multiple times, taking the image variable out of the `images()` function and putting it inside the `init()` function, but the same thing happened.

3- I have already tried modifying the image, and I also tested several other images to see if the issue was with the file, but other issues occurred.

I am using a specific library, so I hope to not have to use another library unless it is necessary.